# Why is Java placing the string before the word and not after?

Tags: java, regex

from the String value want to getting word before and after the `<in>`

```
String ref = "application<in>rid and test<in>efd";
        int result = ref.indexOf("<in>");
        int result1 = ref.lastIndexOf("<in>");
        String firstWord = ref.substring(0, result);
        String[] wor = ref.split("<in>");
        for (int i = 0; i < wor.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(wor[i]);
        }
    }
```

my Expected Output

```
String[] output ={application,rid,test,efd}
```

i tried with 2 Option first one `IndexOf` but if the String have more than two `<in>`i 'm not getting my expected output
Second One `split`its also not getting with my expected Output

please suggest best option to getting the word(before and after `<in>`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use an expression like so: `\b([^ ]+?)<in>([^ ]+?)\b` (example [here](https://regex101.com/r/wA8iZ9/1)). This should match the string prior and after the `<in>` tag and place them in two groups.

Thus, given this:

```
    String ref = "application<in>rid and test<in>efd";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b([^ ]+?)<in>([^ ]+?)\\b");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(ref);
    while(m.find())
        System.out.println("Prior: " + m.group(1) + " After: " + m.group(2));
```

Yields:

```
Prior: application After: rid
Prior: test After: efd
```

Alternatively using `split`:

```
    String[] phrases = ref.split("\\s+");
    for(String s : phrases)
        if(s.contains("<in>"))
        {
            String[] split = s.split("<in>");
            for(String t : split)
                System.out.println(t);
        }
```

Yields:

```
application
rid
test
efd
```

Comment: `([^ ]+?)\b`: since you use a non-greedy quantifier here, it is the same to write `(\w+)`, but your idea here was perhaps: `([^ ]+)\b` to grab the largest substring.

Answer (score 2):

Regex is your friend :)

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    String ref = "application<in>rid and test<in>efd";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\w+(?=<in>)|(?<=<in>)\\w+");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(ref);
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group());
    }

}
```

O/P :

```
application
rid
test
efd
```

Comment: I don't think they want `and`, based on there "expected output" ;)

Comment: Thanks, but i dont want "and" only the word befor and after the <in>

Comment: @MadProgrammer - Ouchie !! :)

Answer (score 1):

No doubt matching what you need using `Pattern/Matcher` API is simpler for tis problem.

However if you're looking for a *short and quick* `String#split` solution then you can consider:

```
String ref = "application<in>rid and test<in>efd";

String[] toks = ref.split("<in>|\\s+.*?(?=\\b\\w+<in>)");
```

**Output:**

```
application
rid
test
efd
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qF8nJ5/1)

This regex splits on `<in>` or a pattern that matches a space followed by 0 more chars followed by a word and `<in>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the below code, it is quite simple

```
class StringReplace1
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String ref = "application<in>rid and test<in>efd";

        System.out.println((ref.replaceAll("<in>", " ")).replaceAll(" and "," "));
        }
}
```